# Xaxis Highcharts data loading issue

Tags: javascript, json, date, highcharts

I am implementing a graph using highcharts.js and was facing issues while loading data via json file.
I finally had some success after using this :
http://codeinjs.blogspot.in/2013/07/preprocess-json-data-to-use-in.html

My database has dates in one column, and metric in the other and i'm loading both into the chart using the following code :

```
var processed_json = new Array();
        $.map(filter1, function(obj, i) {
             var date = new Date(obj.date_hour);
             processed_json.push([obj.date_hour, parseInt(obj.metric)]);
        });


        $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType:'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Trend Graph'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Metric, YOY and WOW'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
            min:processed_json.date_hour,
            //minRange: 14 * 24 * 3600000, // fourteen days
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                day: '%b %e'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: processed_json,
            pointStart: processed_json.date_hour,
            //,Date.UTC(2012, 5, 1),
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
                }]
            });     
        });
```

Now, the problem is all the data of metrics are being loaded but the dates in x-axis are not being loaded. 
Earlier there were some random values coming, now it's loading dates from Jan 1 to Jan 14.

My dates are from May 1 -May 14 or it could change with the change in my data in (filter1)

So, basically the y axis is dynamically changing with the data, whereas the x-axis with dates is not.

I have tried

## 1

pointStart: processed_json.date_hour // not working

## 2

chart.series[0].update({
            pointStart: processed_json.date_hour,
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
            data: processed_json.metric
        }, false); //Also not working

---

Can someone give me a better suggestion/approach to solve this problem of getting the dates in my data in the x axis.

Also, if possible when I zoom into the dates i want it to become hours, then minutes and ultimately seconds.

All suggestions are most welcome.

---

Update : 
Image : http://tinypic.com/r/2s0ba4k/8

The image shows the chart that we have plotted and as you can see the x-axis shows 1st jan to 14th jan, whereas in the tooltip the correct date is being shown.

What can I do bring the correct date in the x-axis?

Comment: please check if "processed_json.date_hour" is a array or a singleton value.because start date should be one specific value not a set of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using a couple of other functions namely, getYear(& similar ones) and Date.UTC.

Here is the single line of code I used within the series function of highcharts :

```
pointStart:Date.UTC(new Date(processed_json1[0][0]).getYear(),new Date(processed_json1[0][0]).getMonth(),new Date(processed_json1[0][0]).getDate())
```

Now, using this the dates are coming dynamically as given in the dataset on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how you crate `processed_json`:

```
var processed_json = new Array();
$.map(filter1, function(obj, i) {
     var date = new Date(obj.date_hour);
     processed_json.push([obj.date_hour, parseInt(obj.metric)]);
});
```

So it's array of arrays with `date_hour` and `metric`. Now, `date_hour` should be a number and timstamp in ms, for example: `1402480061843`.

Now, if you will pass properly timestamps and values, then you don't need `pointStart` and `pointInterval`.

Btw, that notation: `pointStart: processed_json.date_hour,` will create `pointStart: 'undefined'`, because `processed_json` is an array, not an object. There should be rather: `processed_json[0][0]`.